# Path Optimization in a matrix?

Tags: java

[image]

I am developing a shortest path finding robot using PC.I am trying to develop its software section in java.For that I need to 
generate a graph data structure from captured image robot's path to be traveled. 
I have managed to generate a metrics from image. What I exactly need find the path in this matrix and convert that to a graph

I know this will be stupid attempt if I consider all the pixel as nodes of graph .I have searched and found there is an algorithm named Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm  to reduce the serious points in a Line .I am new to this ,Can I use this algorithm to reduce the points ?

Comment: It's main purpose - to reduce amount of points. So it can help you. But for example on a picture, what is your task? What graph should you build?

Comment: My aim  is to build a path finding robot. User can draw a robot path (maze ) on floar. FIrst section of my program is to capture this path image and convert that to a graph. I got image of path by capturing,after when I try to convert this path  to a connection of nodes. (Graph),there where somany pixels on a point. I have to make this is an optimized graph then only i can apply shortest path finding algorithm on this graph . pic shows the matrix foam of the image. I have drawn redmark to the points needed. I have to make that as a single line conection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding it correctly, the RDP algorithm reduces the number of points in a curve, meaning, if there is a curve that has many line segments, the RDP algorithm only reduces the number of points in the curve. What you'll need here is line thinning or skeletonization. Personally I don't know any image processing libraries available for Java, but there will be some around. After thinning the lines, then you can use the RDP algorithm to reduce the number of points in the path for your robot.